# .NET Core Bypass or turn off [Authorize(Roles="")] during local development

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I have below code to bypass adding authentication during local development, I am using Azure AD & .NET Core.

```
#if !DEBUG
            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
               .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
#endif
```

However since I have my controller protected by Authorize attribute, how do I bypass the Authorize attribute inside Controller during local development:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Buyer")]
public class ProductController : ApiBaseController
{
}
```

In .NET Framework I have below code to override the Authorize attribute:

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
     #if DEBUG
        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            return true;
        }
     #endif
    }
```

What is the equivalent code for .NET Core ? or is there any other way we can override Authorize attribute in Startup.cs class ?

Comment: Put a flag in the startup code that doesn’t apply the auth pipeline if in dev mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working using below code thanks to Jeremy for right direction:

In Controller class I used Policy based authorization:

```
 [Authorize(Policy= "Buyer")]
 public class ProductController : ApiBaseController
 {
 }
```

In the start.cs we can add authentication & authorization based on the DEBUG conditions:

```
#if !DEBUG
            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
               .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(config.GetSection("AzureAd"));
#endif

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                // policy for read access
                options.AddPolicy("Buyer", policy =>
                {
#if DEBUG
                    policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
#else
                    policy.RequireRole("Buyer");
#endif
                });
            });
```

For RequireAuthenticatedUser() in debug mode we use below code to add AllowAnonymous attribute on all the controllers:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
#if DEBUG
                endpoints.MapControllers().WithMetadata(new AllowAnonymousAttribute());
#else
                    endpoints.MapControllers();
#endif
            });
```

Answer (score 4):

Rather than explicitly specifying the roles each controller requires with `[Authorize(Roles...`, you can use `[Authorize(Policy...` to add a layer of indirection.

That way you can decide in your `StartUp` class (or in a `IConfigureOptions<AuthorizationOptions>` service), exactly what each policy means. Including any other weird requirements you might have.

```cs
[Authorize(Policy= "Buyer")]
public class ProductController : ApiBaseController

...

services.AddAuthorization(o =>
{
    o.AddPolicy("Buyer", b => {
#if DEBUG
        b.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
#else
        b.RequireRole("Buyer");
#endif
    });
});
```

Comment: Nvm I got it thank you

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use a `IClaimsTransformation` for that.  In this case, I'll just add a role to everyone, but when it's wired up it will only do it if you're in development (note: You'll need to make sure the environment variable is set correctly so `IsDevelopment` works).

###### AddRolesClaimsTransformation.cs

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Adds roles to a user on the fly, this will hard code a Buyer role for everyone.
/// </summary>
public class AddRolesClaimsTransformation : IClaimsTransformation
{
    public async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        // Clone current identity
        var clone = principal.Clone();
        var ident = (ClaimsIdentity)clone.Identity;

        ident.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Buyer"));

        return clone;
    }
}
```

###### Startup.cs

```cs
// Only in dev
if (builder.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    builder.Services.AddScoped<IClaimsTransformation, AddRolesClaimsTransformation>();
}
```

This should work for ASP.NET Core 3.1 according to the Microsoft docs.  I tested it against .NET 6 however (in .NET 6 the templates for new sites move the `Startup.cs` stuff into `Program.cs`).

One other side note, if you rely on the `IsDevelopment` plumbing that's on the `WebHostEnvironment` you won't have to use the compiler directives.  That way once the environment is setup it will just work however you deploy it there (e.g. there isn't a chance an accidental Debug build will make it into an environment it's not supposed to be in).